# Cloning an instance of a running proccess, windows or linux

Tags: linux, windows

Is there a way (in linux or windows) to make a clone of an running proccess?.
For example, i have a game running or an notepad writing some stuff and i want just to clone it.
i know there is a way if **you writing the program** with system call fork() but im asking outside of the programming view from the user point of view.

Comment: Linux: attach `gdb` to process & run `call fork()<enter>detach<enter>`

Comment: Note that you can't use fork() on Windows, even from inside the process.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no way**, unless the program explicitly supports this kind of operation.

Even if you manage to clone the complete program state, you'd immediate run into **resource conflicts** on dynamically allocated resources, e.g., both clones using same file descriptors, same memory references, identical GUI resources etc.

It's conceivable to perform a clone, though, if you clone the program *together* with its entire environment (hardware and OS) -- like, creating a clone of a virtual machine that's running your program.